# How to get the block height with zero-height blocks with margins inside

Tags: jquery, html, css

I cant get the real height value of wrapper block. Here the example HTML:

```css
.one, .two {
    height: 100px;
    background-color: black;
}
    
.three, .four {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="one"></div>
    <div class="two"></div>
    <div class="three" ></div>
    <div class="four" ></div>
</div>
```

`.height(), .outerHeight(), .innerHeight()` return the same value - 200. But if i'll add `border-bottom:1px solid transparent`, the height value will be 211.

So how can i get the height value without adding 1px border?

Comment: Assuming `.three .four` have no content the height can only be 200. IIRC `margin-bottom` won't be applied until the div has content.

Comment: This is partly true, if there is another block underneath .wrapper it's pulled down, so the physical size(collisiion size) of .wrapper is 210px.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When inspecting the HTML in a browser (here Chrome), the wrapper `div` has a height of 200 and the `div`s three and four have zero height, although their margin is indicated below the wrapper `div`. As soon as the `div`s have content, their height is different from 0 and adds to the wrapper's height.

HTML to experiment with:

```html
    <!doctype html>
    <html>
    <head>
      <style>
        .one, .two {
          height: 100px;
          background-color: red;
        }
    
        .three, .four {
          margin-bottom: 10px;
          background-color: yellow;
        }
      </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="one"></div>
      <div class="two"></div>
      <div class="three" ></div>
      <div class="four" ></div>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

The following HTML gives a height of 210px:

```html
    <!doctype html>
    <html>
    <head>
      <style>
        .one, .two {
          height: 100px;
          background-color: red;
        }
    
        .three, .four {
          height: 0px;
          margin-bottom: 10px;
          background-color: yellow;
        }
      </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="wrapper" id="wrapper">
      <div class="one"></div>
      <div class="two"></div>
      <div class="three">&nbsp;</div>
      <div class="four">&nbsp;</div>
    </div>
    <script>
      console.log(document.getElementById("wrapper").clientHeight);
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

- added `&nbsp;` as content to the `div`s
- added `height: 0px;` to the CSS

Comment: thanks, in someway it's a good solution, but not in my case where i cant control which blocks will be empty.

Comment: do you have control overf something at all, e.g. CSS? how about adding       height: 1px; margin-top: -1px; ?

Comment: Thats what im doing now but i wonder maybe there's another way or  i missed some CSS rules.